# Displaying images in React before uploading them

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I'm creating form that let's user upload few images. I'm using react-dropzone to make it cooler ;p
Unfortunately after choosing image my  has undefined src attribute. 
Here's my code:

```
export const ImageInput = (props) => {
  const imagePreviews = props.images.map(image => {
     return <ImagePreview key={image.id} image={image.image}/>
   })

  return (
     <div>
       <Dropzone
         className="dropzone"
         multiple={true}
         accept="image/*"
         onDrop={props.addImage}> I STORE THE IMAGES IN PARENT COMPONENT
         <p>drop or click here</p>
      </Dropzone>
      <ul>
        {imagePreviews}
      </ul>
    </div>
   )
 }
```

And this is single ImagePreview component

```
export const ImagePreview = (props) => {
  let imagePreviewUrl = "";
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(props.image)
  reader.onloadend = () => {
      imagePreviewUrl = reader.result;
    }
  console.log(imagePreviewUrl)

  return (
    <li className="">
      <img className="image-preview" src={imagePreviewUrl} />
    </li>
  )
}
```

Using react tools for browser I can prove that images are being saved correctly
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGGIz.png)

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reader.onloadend is async so "ImagePreview" will return before imagePreviewUrl has value. You cant use this code for "ImagePreview"

```
class ImagePreview extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.state= {imagePreviewUrl: ''} 
   }

   componentWillMount() {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(props.image)
     reader.onloadend = () => {
       this.setState({imagePreviewUrl: reader.result})
     }
   }
}
```